# Jquery Mobile css and js not loading correctly after Dynamic jquery mobile PopUp - c# .net MVC

Tags: jquery, html, css, model-view-controller, mobile

i created a page for login popup with jquery mobile popup. Login screen working and login working successfully. But i want to use jquery mobile Flip toggle switch or other features correctly int the pop-up. But not working.

This is my css and js files on index.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="~/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

this is my ajax call script;

```
    $('.makelogin').click(function () {
        $("#popupLogin").popup("open");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Login/MainLogin',
            success: function (returnval) {
                $("#popupLogin").html(returnval);
                $("#popupLogin").popup("reposition", { positionTo: 'window' });
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is my div;

```
<div id="popupLogin" data-role="popup" rel="external" data-overlay-theme="b"></div>
```

I am trying to add this simple code, but i could not. its not getting styles and js functions not working;

```
<form>
<label for="flip-3">Flip toggle switch:</label>
<select name="flip-3" id="flip-3" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

when i copy and paste html code, from page source, styles working but js functions not working;

```
<div class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-slider-track ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini" role="application"><span style="width: 100%;" role="img" class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active">On</span><span style="width: 0%;" role="img" class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b">Off</span><div class="ui-slider-inneroffset"><a style="left: 100%;" aria-labelledby="flip-3-label" title="On" aria-valuetext="On" aria-valuenow="on" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuemin="0" role="slider" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-shadow ui-slider-handle-snapping" href="#"></a></div></div>
```

Comment: i tired this but its not working;
[link](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/).

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it. Answer maybe helps for you.

i used

`$('#popupLogin').trigger('create');`

So;

```
    function openPopup() {
        $("#popupLogin").popup({ positionTo: "window" }).popup('open');
    }

    $('.xxx').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Login/MainLogin',
            success: function(returnval) {
                $("#popupLogin").html(returnval);
                $('#popupLogin').trigger('create');
                setTimeout(openPopup, 100);
            }
        });
    });
```

i fixed reposition also...